GoogleMobileAds dead code causing warning
I am getting started with some GoogleMobileAds in my SwiftUI application on iOS. Trying to determine a warning in my console, I am left with the following code snipped:

import GoogleMobileAds
let a = {
    GADAdLoader(
        adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-some~id",
        rootViewController: nil,
        adTypes: [.native], options: nil)
}


Without every having to execute a, I am getting the following warnings at runtime:
Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
Synchronous remote object proxy returned error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
Updating selectors failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}
Updating selectors after delegate addition failed with: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service named com.apple.commcenter.coretelephony.xpc was invalidated: failed at lookup with error 3 - No such process.}

Now, when I change the code to the below, the warning disappears:
import GoogleMobileAds
let a = {
//  GADAdLoader(
//      adUnitID: "ca-app-pub-some~id",
//      rootViewController: nil,
//      adTypes: [.native], options: nil)
}

Question: What is going on here; a is never executed and therefore simply dead code. How and why does it trigger a runtime warning?
__
Xcode: Version 15.3 (15E204a)
Dependencies:
    {
      "identity" : "swift-package-manager-google-mobile-ads",
      "kind" : "remoteSourceControl",
      "location" : "https://github.com/googleads/swift-package-manager-google-mobile-ads.git",
      "state" : {
        "revision" : "41118048ffdeb8ef6c0f2207b685f84fba260f56",
        "version" : "11.4.0"
      }
    },
    {
      "identity" : "swift-package-manager-google-user-messaging-platform",
      "kind" : "remoteSourceControl",
      "location" : "https://github.com/googleads/swift-package-manager-google-user-messaging-platform.git",
      "state" : {
        "revision" : "9b68aa69fb508f0274853e226c734151a973c7b7",
        "version" : "2.4.0"
      }
    }

